# Как найти файл php через nuxt.js?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Мне нужно обратиться к файлу mail.php для отправки формы/ через node не могу, т.к. я его не знаю (сделаю по старинке)

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
       var formId = $(this).attr('id');
       var formNm = $('#' + formId);
       var msg   = $(formNm).serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '~/static/mail.php', // вот я не знаю как к нему тут обратиться
     data: msg,
     success: function(data) {
       console.log('Отправлено')
 },
     error:  function(xhr, str){
       console.log('Ошибка')
     }
   });
})
```

В итоге ошибка 404, потому не может найти файл
Что делать? куда его пихнуть?

Comment: Очень интересно нашли ли решение, столкнулся с такой же проблемой..